# Nvidia Geforce GT 710 no video output with Dell Poweredge T420 - Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, xorg, 19.04

I've newely installed Ubuntu 19.04 onto my Dell Poweredge T420 server. Ubuntu runs fine on built in graphics but refuses to display any output from the graphics card (Nvidia GT 710). I've tried every version (purging first) but with no luck.

```
Redacted@redacted:~$ prime-select query
nvidia
```

Below shows that the driver is installed:

```
Redacted@redacted:~$ lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA"
06:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd. G200eR2
    Subsystem: Dell G200eR2
    Kernel driver in use: mgag200
--
0a:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208B [GeForce GT 710] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] GK208B [GeForce GT 710]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

Ubuntu Drivers:

```
redacted@redacted:~$ sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:0a:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd0000128Bsv00001462sd00008C93bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GK208B [GeForce GT 710]
driver   : nvidia-driver-418 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

Nvidia-Settings

```
redacted@redacted:~$ nvidia-settings

ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system


(nvidia-settings:4997): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 13:35:03.097: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
** Message: 13:35:03.102: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: 13:35:03.102: PRIME: is it supported? no
```

Picture from ubuntu:

[Blank nvidia X Server Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kieNz.png)

[Software and updates - additional drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOERg.png)

Any suggestions would be really appreciated!!!

Hopefully some of the below is of help!

EDIT: Forgot to mention I've disabled built in graphics on the T420 but it then fails to boot at all

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue with an HP Microserver Gen10+. It also has an integrated Matrox G200, and I also have added a GeForce GT 710. Like you I have installed the proprietary drivers, like you I get a blank Nvidia X Server Settings window. While the GeForce drivers are loaded, I haven't been able to tell Ubuntu (I'm running 20.04) to "switch" to the other graphics adapter. No luck seeking help on the net: Did you find a solution? If so, sharing would be appreciated! :-) (My only luck seems to be that disabling the Matrox in BIOS, while suboptimal, seems to work for me…)

Answer (score 0):

I have a few hunches and suggestions. I faced this issue with the Nvidia 720 and linux mint, but most things should be relevant to this case. I would've liked to comment as this is not all tried and tested but I do not have the reputation to, so here goes.

Your GPU is visible so it seems like you have already chosen `Switchable Graphics` over `UMA` in the Boot Setup. If you haven't, then its something you should do.

The next thing, I can think of is the order in which the nvidia drivers and nvidia prime were installed. The ideal sequence is to install prime first and then the drivers. Just to be sure -
1. Uninstall both the drivers and nvidia prime.
2. Use `apt-get autoremove` and `apt-get autoclean` to get rid of any remnants.
3. First, reinstall nvidia-prime.
3. Then reinstall the drivers.

Rebooting after this should enable the drivers and the display should work.
It's pretty basic and you might've already tried all this, but I hope it helps!

Comment: Thankyou for your reply!! I just did exactly what you said and it gets to the login screen and i'm able to login. Then i'm presented with a black screen and it loops back to the login screen. I'm not entirely sure what driver its using

Comment: Tanmay, I don't think `prime` is any help in this case, since Prime is – as far as I have been able to tell – aimed solely at Intel (i)GPUs. I have the same issue as OP, and Prime is not the solution. :-(